# add/removeClass doesn`t work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

This works correctly on browser but doesn't work on iPhone.
Also I used the

```
var $event = ($ua.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
```

It also doesn`t work on iPhone

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn_mod" onclick="mod()">
<div class="mod_seciton">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mod_section.active{
    display:none;
}
.mod_section{
    display:block;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function mod(){
    $('.mod_section').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".btn_mod" ).click(function() {
     mod();
     alert("just for your own test..");
});
```

Comment: and if your mod() called but not work addClass , share your app link to debug it for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply.@kiamoz
I did but it seems that it also works on browser but not on iPhone.
Also the alert doesn`t pop up on iPhone.

Comment: This is url for that:
    https://www.pacifictintlv.com/residential-simulators
the button is prestige Series and please check on mobile mode.